# Unpredictible results with buttons (better their eventhandlers) inside conditional rendered elements (i. e. panels)

Tags: event-handling, xpages, renderer

I am trying to hide/show a panel based on a condition like this

```
<xp:panel id="panelUsersInput">
 <!--<xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:return ((getComponent("optAttendees").getAttributes().get("value")=="defined"));}]]></xp:this.rendered>-->
 <xp:inputText id="namUsersInput">
  <xp:typeAhead mode="partial" minChars="3" ignoreCase="true" var="lupUsersInput">
   <xp:this.valueList><![CDATA[#{javascript:@DbLookup( [ database.getServer(), 'names.nsf' ], '($VIMPeople)', lupUsersInput, 1, '[PARTIALMATCH]' );}]]></xp:this.valueList>
  </xp:typeAhead>
 </xp:inputText>
 <xp:button value="" id="btnAddUser" styleClass="button add clear" title="add attendant">
  <xp:span/>
  <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="panelUsersList" execMode="partial" execId="panelSelectionAttendees">
   <xp:this.onStart><![CDATA[(dojo.byId("#{id:namUsersInput}").value!="");]]></xp:this.onStart>
   <xp:this.action>
    <![CDATA[#{javascript:
     var lstUsers = getComponent("namUsers").getAttributes().get("value");
     if(typeof(lstUsers)==typeof(java.util.Vector)) {
      lstUsers.push(getComponent("namUsersInput").getAttributes().get("value"));
      lstUsers.sort();
     } else {
      lstUsers = @Trim(@List(lstUsers, getComponent("namUsersInput").getAttributes().get("value")));
     }

     getComponent("namUsersInput").getAttributes().put("value", "");
     getComponent("namUsers").getAttributes().put("value", lstUsers);
    }]]>
   </xp:this.action>
   <xp:this.onComplete><![CDATA[if(dojo.byId("#{id:rpUsersSelection}")) { highlightSection("#{id:rpUsersSelection}"); }]]></xp:this.onComplete>
  </xp:eventHandler>
 </xp:button>
 <div class="clearAll"/>
</xp:panel>
```

As you see I have disabled the rendered option for the panel. With this setting the button inside this panel is working as it is told to.

When enabling the rendered option for the panel, the button inside this panel is doing something, but the result returned by the partial refresh is like reloading the specified section (with the partial id).

Much more interesting is this fact: when the panels rendering condition is false, the event triggered by the button still is rendered. But the eventhandler cannot find it's parent element to bind to. The result is a global binding of this event to the whole page (body-element).

```
XSP.addOnLoad(function() {
...
XSP.attachPartial("view:_id1:_id11:_id47", "view:_id1:_id11:btnAddUser", "view:_id1:_id11:panelSelectionAttendees", "onclick", view__id1__id11__id47_clientSide_onclick, 2, "view:_id1:_id11:panelUsersList", null, "if(dojo.byId(\"view:_id1:_id11:namUsers\").value!=\"\") { dojo.byId(\"view:_id1:_id11:namUsersInput\").value=\"\"; highlightSection(\"view:_id1:_id11:panelUsersList\"); }", null);
...
});
```

Has someone else noticed such a behaviour? I thought that hiding a panel will also hide all underlying elements inside this panel.

Comment: I did a simple test based on your code snippet above (and added the panelUsersList panel). If I set the panelUsersInput panel to not be rendered, I don't see the event. So my guess is that something else (not part of your code snippet) is causing this.

Comment: Well, you're right. The button is not rendered. But the EVENT that is bound to the button is still rendered (see my second edit). And when the condition is set to render the panel... did you click the button? On my page the button does funny things, but not the code I specified for this action.

Comment: In my simple test the event is not rendered. So I'm suspecting that something else on your XPage is the cause of this (so something which is not part of the code snippet above).

Comment: I am going to recode the whole page again. But I am surprised that an XSP.attachPartial still is generated for view:_id1:_id11:btnAddUser, even if the rendering of the panel is set to false.

Comment: The workaround for the given problem is to show/hide the panel on client side by using the style property. But that's not a perfect solution because the whole bunch of dojo libraries are loaded for the typeahead functionality even when the user will never use them.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a known bug

LO73179: XPAGES EVENT HANDLER RENDERING DOES NOT MATCH RENDERING OF PARENT COMPONENT

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1LO73179.